# If string includes and excludes?

Tags: regex, string, language-agnostic, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Match requirement:
If String is between `"` AND includes `\n`

Example (catch YES include "s):

```
NO NO NO    "NO NO NO"  "YES YES
YES"    NO  "NO"
```

This Regex work a half:

```
\"((?!\").)*\"
```

This doesn't work as well:

```
\"((?!\").)*(?!.*\n)\"
```

Did try many cases, but found no solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/"[^"]*\R[^"]*"/
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/hX6gL8/7)!

> Test case:
>
> ```
> NO NO NO    "NO NO NO"  "YES YES
> YES"    NO  "NO"
> ```
>
> Match:
>
> ```
> "YES YES
> YES"
> ```